# localStorage alternative for Phonegap

Tags: cordova, local-storage

I tried using localStorage and globalStorage for storing small amounts of data locally in the browser(from local page), but got security exception with globalStorage and the data didn't persist with localStorage.

Cookies are too small and using files and databases seems like overkill and may be unstable across platforms. Do I really have to use files or databases to store ~20kb of data? Are there alternatives to localStorage or other ways to work around this issue?

Comment: Perhaps the question you need to be asking is "What's wrong with my code that localStorage isn't persisting?" Because it should.

Comment: I wish it would be my fault, but as far as I searched, the page must have a real domain and local files on the user side have no way of persisting data between sessions, but I might be wrong.

Comment: According to what I see, localStorage should work with a phoneGap app. http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#localStorage http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300667/localstorage-doesnt-persist-when-the-app-is-quit-from-memory-phonegap

Comment: There's definitely something else going on. Im using almost stock PGB service, with PG 2.7 (most recent supported by pushwoosh plugin I need), and localStorage definently does not persist on android.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had no problem getting this small sample to persist data between application launches in the iPhone 4.3 simulator.

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    //window.localStorage.setItem("key", "value");

    var value = window.localStorage.getItem("key");

    navigator.notification.alert(value);
}
```

Uncomment to set the initial value, then comment it out to test persistence on subsequent launches.

Comment: i had problem when re-setting items in same key m using phonegap 2.0 on xcode